# Get rid of xs:type attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

Consider the following xml:

```
<Awesome xs:type="AB">
  <a />
  <b />
</Awesome>
<Awesome xs:type="CD">
  <f />
  <c />
  <e />
  <d />
</Awesome>
```

This can be specified with this schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="base" abstract="true" />
<xs:complexType name="AB">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="base">
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="a" />
        <xs:element name="b" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="CD">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="base">
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="c" />
        <xs:element name="d" />
        <xs:element name="e" />
        <xs:element name="f" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Considering the potential users of the schema, I’d like to keep the xml as simple as possible (and that’s why I used `all` and not `sequence`) and prefer to get rid of the `xs:type` attributes.

Can this be specified in a schema? Maybe with a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing for writing XSD (and the simplest thing for users, it says here) is to follow the principle that if one Awesome element is required to contain an `a` and a `b`, and another is required to contain some sequence of `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f`, then they are not the same kind of thing and should have different names.

If you call them Awesome-ab and Awesome-cdef, the schema is trivial and it's easy for users to understand when they are allowed to use `a` and `b` as children and when they use the other elements.

The `xsi:type` mechanism was added precisely for cases where the vocabulary designer wants to call different things by the same name but still validate them against different types.

If you don't want to use different names for the elements of different type, and you don't want to use `xsi:type` to signal the difference in type, how do you propose that the validator should know which type to use?  Clairvoyance would be a good approach, but I understand it's hard to implement.

Comment: I’d call it “type inference” instead of “clairvoyance” :) However, I agree that it is (relatively) hard to implement.

Comment: Fair point.  Schema languages could be designed with type inference in mind; XSD is not one of them.  XSD is designed to make it possible to identify, at the start tag for each element, which element declaration and type definition should be used for its validation, without the intervention of anything that would merit the name *inference*.